# Search lines with matching Pattern in File but replace string matching with second pattern in same line

Tags: bash, macos, shell, awk, sed

Need help from Shell/Bash Geeks especially on Mac OS

I want to search a pattern in bunch of source files but want to replace another string in lines having this pattern.

For example:

```
Private const String myTestString = @“VAL15”; // STRING-REPLACE-VAL##
```

Here, I want to search my source file for pattern “STRING-REPLACE-VAL##” and then replace VAL15 with VAL20 in same.

Output:

```
private const String myTestString = @“VAL20”; // STRING—REPLACE-VAL##
```

Tried below command but not working as expected.

```
sed -i '.bkp' '/,STRING—REPLACE-VAL##/ {; s/,VAL15,/,VAL20,/;}' myTestFile.cpp
```

**Q2** - Is it possible to search for `STRING—REPLACE-VAL##` and then search for matching pattern `@"VAL??"` in same line and replace `15` by `20`.

sed supports search & replacing the same pattern very easily but not sure if sed supports to search pattern but replace another string in the matching line?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please wrap your samples in code tags and explain your requirements more precisely.

Comment: Shared command in above post i.e. "sed -i '.bkp' '/,STRING-REPLACE-VAL##/ {; s/,VAL15,/,VAL20,/;}' myTestFile.cpp" but it is not allowing to edit the same.

Comment: Note, that when you're entering or editing a question in SO, you get a preview below.   There's also a yellow bar with help icons to let you know how to do formatting, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww -- just came across this -- while OP didn't format text properly (note that this is their first post), they did mention a specific problem, the desired behavior, and showed an attempt to address the problem that didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could likely do it with something simple, like so:

```
sed -i 's/VAL15\(.*STRING-REPLACE-VAL\)/VAL20\1/'
```

If a line contains `VAL15` followed by `STRING-REPLACE-VAL` it would replace `VAL15` with `VAL20`.

If order isn't guarenteed, you can of course get more complicated:

```
sed -E '/STRING-REPLACE-VAL/bx ; b ; :x ; s/VAL15/VAL20/ ;'
```

Note that the `;`'s are GNU-specific, and may not work on all platforms (I believe you can use `-e`'s instead on the other platforms).   This statement basically says: if the line matches `STRING-REPLACE-VAL` then branch to label `:x`, otherwise branch to the end.   If you go to label `x:`, then run the `s/VAL15/VAL20` on the line.   See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html) for a reference

Comment: It worked. Stackoverflow developer community rocks :-)

Comment: sed -i '.bkp' 's/VAL15\(.*STRING-REPLACE-VAL\)/VAL20\1/' myTestFile.cpp